# Component is not re-rendered after invoke StateHasChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I have read the article "[3 Ways to Communicate Between Components in Blazor](https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/)" and have tried to do the same.
I have message component under the @body and depending on user actions in the @body components message has to be changed

```
@inject ClientMessage clientMessage
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@using Site.Shared.Components

<div class="sidebar">
<AdminMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
   <Message/>
</div>

@code
{
    protected async Task ChangeState()
    {
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        clientMessage.MsgChange += ChangeState;
    }
 }
```

Message component:

```
@inject ClientMessage clientMessage
<div style="@(IsVisble ? "display:block" : "display:none")" class="@MsgClass" role="alert">
    @if (clientMessage != null)
    {
        @clientMessage.Message
    }
</div>

@code {

    public bool IsVisble
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(@clientMessage.Message))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    public string MsgClass
    {
        get
        {
            if (clientMessage == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            string msgClass;

            switch (clientMessage.MsgType)
            {
                case EMsgType.Info:
                    msgClass = "alert alert-info";
                    break;
                case EMsgType.Success:
                    msgClass = "alert alert-success";
                    break;
                case EMsgType.Warning:
                    msgClass = "alert alert-warning";
                    break;
                case EMsgType.Error:
                    msgClass = "alert alert-danger";
                    break;
                case EMsgType.NoMsg:
                default:
                    msgClass = string.Empty;
                    break;
            }

            return msgClass;
        }
    }
}
```

Message class

```
public class ClientMessage
{
    public event Func<Task> MsgChange;

    public ClientMessage(string msg, EMsgType msgType)
    {
        this.Message = msg;
        this.MsgType = msgType;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }

    public void SetMsg(string msg, EMsgType msgType)
    {
        this.Message = msg;
        this.MsgType = msgType;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public EMsgType MsgType { get; set; }

    private void NotifyStateChanged()
    {
        if (MsgChange != null)
        {
            MsgChange.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

ClientMessage class is injected as a singleton by DI. If I invoke SetMsg(newMsgm, msgType) in the @body components then ChangeState() method is invoked but nothing happened, I mean component is not re-rendered.  If I instead "InvokeAsync" use "Invoke" I have an error "The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.". If I reload the page I can see Message.

What do I wrong and how can I force to re-render message component?

Comment: Your message component has no parameters, so Blazor will assume it is static. If you moved the `code` section of your MainLayout to the Message component, it would re-render itself whenever the message changed. You should implement IDisposable as well - so you can unsubscribe from the MsgChange event - for completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this issue. Maybe it will help someone.

I localized the problem - when @body was changed after NavigationManager.NavigateTo("some_page") had been invoked StateHasChanged() does not re-rendered message component. I tried different places where I can fire StateHasChanged() and if I moved it to Message.razor it stars to work as expected.

It is [better to read the documentation at the beggining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0#invoke-component-methods-externally-to-update-state) than articles:)

Comment: Documentation worth it.